# What is the way to add additional fields to attachments in 3.5+?

Tags: uploads, attachments, media, attachment-fields-to-edit

I used to use [attachment_fields_to_edit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_edit) filter, but it seems that in 3.5+ it has been dropped. What is the new way of adding additional attachment fields?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that it wasn't dropped, but - deprecated. In 3.6 it operates in compatibility mode. To make a new field appear in media popup, one should set additional param - `show_in_modal` to *true* (helpful post [here](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/attachment-editing-now-with-full-post-edit-ui/)):

```
$form_fields['thumb-url'] = array(
    'label' => __('Thumbnail Url'),
    'input' => 'html',
    'html'  => <p> ... some html here ... </p>,
    'show_in_modal' => true // <- this one
);
```

But - still, the whole thing is deprecated and doomed to be dropped sooner or later. There should be a new way of doing things. Anyone knows what that'd be?

Comment: The filter is [still there](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/media.php). What makes you think the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

`attachment_fields_to_edit` is still there in 3.6. It is in [`/wp-admin/includes/media.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/media.php) in a couple of places. Perhaps usage has changed, or something has changed that has broken your code but without that code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: It stopped working, but now I know that it requires additional params to show up. However as I see it operates in compatibility mode and is deprecated in general. Should I assume that there is no way to extend this updated part of WordPress anymore?